# When adding eggs to scratch cake batter, why are you supposed to add them one at a time?

Tags: eggs, cake, batter

When making a cake from scratch I have always added my eggs one at a time, mixing in between each, because this is how I learned from my mother. I just can't remember why this is supposed to be beneficial. Does anyone know why this should produce a different result than adding them all at the same time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The key thing here is a substance called** [`Lecithin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin) and it is found in your Incredible, Edible Egg!

Doing the adding of the egg one-by-one, plus a few other things are...

> **in the service of creating a stable emulsion of liquid and fat in the batter**. When this is done correctly, the cake will have a springy, even crumb, great flavor, and light texture. **If the batter is not properly emulsified**, *the resulting cake can be uneven and flat, flavorless, and have a heavy texture.* It's even possible for the cake to "fall" or sink into itself when baking.
>
> An emulsion is the suspension of small globules of one liquid in a second liquid with which the first will not mix, such as oil and vinegar. **To create an emulsion, we slowly add eggs to the butter mixture, one at a time, beating rapidly to suspend the water from the butter and egg whites in the fats from the butter and egg yolks**. *Lecithin, an emulsifier found in eggs, helps to stabilize the emulsion, as does aeration from steady, rapid beating.*
>
> **Adding the eggs slowly makes it easier disperse the liquid, and promote even suspension of liquid in fat.**

So to recap, liquid and fat do not mix together. The egg has Lecithin that acts like a bond that keeps those 2 together. By flooding the mixture with the substance that will act like a binder (egg), *you actually make it harder for all the water in the* **butter / eggs** *to bind to the fat in the* **butter / eggs**.

### Picture of Emulsion

[image]

[image]
Take note that in this picture, the oil to make the mayonnaise was added too fast in the failed picture. Take a look at thesproatingseed.com link below for even more information on emulsion!

This answer was made possible by [SeriousEats.com](http://sweets.seriouseats.com/2011/08/sweet-technique-mixing-cake-batter.html), [IOANA.BLOG](http://blog.ioanacolor.com/2011/06/emulsion/), and [TheSproutingSeed.com](http://thesproutingseed.com/homemade-mayonnaise/)